# How to display image in my view blade from storage/app/public/student_img folder in laravel 8

Tags: image, laravel-8, public, app-folder

```
I have stored the images inside the storage/app/public/student_img but am not able to fetch images using any method inside the blade.

my filesystem.php setting is
'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
// this is the code
```

Fetching image like this **src='storage/app/student_img/{{ $stud->photo }}'**

```
Please help me.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you run :

```
php artisan storage:link
```

yet?

If you have a folder at /storage/app/public/student_img in which you are saving uploaded files, then you would need to put a symlink to that folder within the /public folder.

Once that has been done, you can then include an image from the /storage/app/public/student_img folder in your blade template using :

```
<img src="{{url('student_img/image.png')}}">
```

Comment: Yes, It's working after "  php artisan storage:link   " then asset('storage/student_img/'.$stud->photo)  thanks for the answer. It is really helpful for me

Comment: Please feel free to mark it as the accepted answer, in that case.